# Using method on object in overriden abstract generic function in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics

Here is the following code

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract <E> void foo(E e);
}
```

the subclass:

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public <OtherClass> void foo(OtherClass oc) {
        oc.someOtherClassMethod(); //here compiler cannot see method
    }
}
```

and class with main

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
        A a = new B();
        a.foo(oc);
    }
}
```

the error I get:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
...
symbol:   method someOtherClassMethod()
  location: variable oc of type OtherClass
  where OtherClass is a type-variable:
    OtherClass extends Object declared in method <OtherClass>write(OtherClass )
1 error
```

Why cannot I use the someOtherClassMethod()? Without generics everything works, but I would like to be able to extend other classes in which I override foo() method

**Solution:**

```
public abstract class A <E> {
    public abstract void foo(E e);
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class B extends A<OtherClass> {
    @Override
    public void foo(OtherClass oc) {
        oc.someOtherClassMethod();
    }
}
```

However, now I need use in main function:

```
A<OtherClass> a = new B();
```

Comment: Because `otherClass` is a generic parameter, so could be anything.

Comment: Show otherClass.java file does it have method someOtherClassMethod

Comment: Note that conventionally, Java types and type parameters begin with capital letters.  i.e. `OtherClass`, not `otherClass`.

Comment: Yes it has someOtherClassMethod, without generics everything works. @Oliver So it is possible to make it work with a generic parameter?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using generics here?  It's difficult to suggest a meaningful solution without understanding this.

Comment: I think you should consider using <T extends IYourInterface>, where IYourInterface contains the declaration of someOtherClassMethod().
Here is a nice reference:
https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-java/collections/extending-generic-classes-implementing-generic-interfaces-reading.cfm

Comment: I would like to have several subclasses in which I must implement method foo() which takes different type of parameters in every subclass. So I think that generics could be appropriate.

Comment: It looks like `<E>` should be a generic parameter on the _class_, not the _method._

Comment: Thanks! using generic on the class instead of method works fine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
public abstract class A<E> {
  public abstract void foo(E e);
}
```

and

```
public class B extends A<OtherClass>
```